# Display message on gridPagingToolbar based on restDataStore length

Tags: html, jsp, datastore

I am new to jsp / servlet and related domains.
I am trying to display a message on a gridPagingToolbar based on length of myDataStoreDs.

```
<j:gridPagingToolbar dataStoreId="myDataStoreDs" gridId="myExampleGrid" exportEnabled="true">
        <jsp:attribute name="startItems">
            myLib.Util.removeNulls([null, "${message}"            
                ,   <j:button type='edit' labelKey="myLabel" handler="myHandler" hidden="true" itemId="myBtn"/>            
            ])
        </jsp:attribute>
</j:gridPagingToolbar>
```

The variable "message" should have a String based upon the length of the datastore - such as null for datastore length 0, some custom message otherwise.
I should do this check on my html.jsp, and the datastore is being populated by a rest POST through a js.jsp.

Any suggestions on the code to read the datastore length and populate the message? I have used

```
<c:if test="someRequestAttribute">
```

for other purposes, but not able to get the correct way to implement this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
<j:gridPagingToolbar dataStoreId="myDataStoreDs" gridId="myExampleGrid" exportEnabled="true">
        <jsp:attribute name="startItems">
            myLib.Util.removeNulls([null
                ,   {
                    xtype: 'tbtext',
                    itemId: 'toolbarText',                       
                    text: "<j:jsMessage key='diplay text' bundle='bundle.myResourceBundle' />"

                }                
                ,   <j:button type='edit' labelKey="myLabel" handler="myHandler" hidden="true" itemId="myBtn"/>            
        ])
        </jsp:attribute>
</j:gridPagingToolbar>
```

In the js.jsp part, the rest datastore length can be checked.

```
var text = pageConfigName.myExampleGrid.down("#toolbarText");    
if(pageConfigName.myDatastoreDs.getTotalCount() == 0) {                                         
            text.hidden = true;
    }
```